# Node.js returns undefinded from conn.query

Tags: javascript, metadata-api, node.js

After getting a good connection to SalesForce my basic query fails with an "undefined".  I have executed the query in Developer console, so I think it's okay.  Is there a syntax issue I'm missing?

```
http.createServer(function(request,response) {
var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
//console.log("The URL:"+request.url);
if (url_parts.pathname == "/test" && request.method == "GET") {
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
response.write('\n<h1>Demo Data Copy Begin</h1>\n');

salesforce.getOrgConnection("user@id.com", "Password", "TOKEN>>>>>>", function (scs5, conn2) {
  try {
    var connDate = +new Date();
    console.log("Got the connection..at:" + connDate);
    if (scs5) {
      console.log("Conn success");
     // response.write('\n\nConn success!');

      try {
        conn2.query("SELECT Id, FolderName, Name FROM Report", function(scs6, result) {
          if (!scs6) { return console.log("If " + result); }
          else { return console.log("Else " + result); }
        });
      }
      catch (ex) {
        console.log("Error in conn2.query: " + ex);
      }
    }
    else{
      console.log("Error on S/F connection-01");
      response.end('\n\nError on S/F connection');
    }
  }
  catch (ex) {
    console.log("Error on S/F connection-02" + ex);
    response.end('\n\nError on S/F connection');
  }
});
response.end('\n\nDemo Data Copy End!');
console.log("TEST!!");
} else{
 display404(url_parts.pathname,request,response);
}
```

Console:

> ```
> TEST!!
> getOrgConnections Login took 606ms
> Got the connection..at:1481040394540
> Conn success
> Else undefined
> ```

Comment: Suggest you paste your code into http://jshint.com/ for a quick syntax check.

Comment: @KeithC - good idea.  Nothing was flagged however.

Comment: Turns out you cannot use the same syntax as the Developer console to query reports.  Does anyone know the accepted field name for FolderName?  Pulling that field allows the query to run.  I'm pretty sure I need this to get the metadata out of the ORG.